# Организация социальной сети

Tags: веб-программирование

Вопрос состоит в следующем. По какой технологии построен процесс в соц сетях, что после регистрации появляется страница с вашим id? Как я понимаю, на сервере появляется страница с вашим адресом (к примеру www.set/yourid). Или нет? Какие инструменты используются? И где можно прочесть литературу?

Comment: Это уже известно. Задача - пользователь заполняет форму, данные передаются в базу и на их основе генерируется страница (не соц сеть) Но я туплю и никак немогу понять как это страница появляется на хосте? Если он ввел Artem => будет www.website/Artem (почему нет расширения понятно - mod_rewrite) и теперь если в обратиться http://www.website/Artеm - любому пользователю будет видна эта страница то есть на хосте данная (новая) страница существует - но каким образом она там появилась? мы же на сервер ничего не загружали.

Comment: ахтунг... 'застрелился'

Comment: ну не все мега программисты.

Comment: да тут не в программировании дело, а в логике! вернее в ее отсутствии)

Comment: Да, ужжж...

Comment: ахаха @Palmervan. Ну ты умеешь насмешьтXD

Comment: да, я Петросян еще тот!

Comment: >мы же на сервер ничего не загружали.

В ответе есть и ответ на это вопрос. Пробуй сделать новости, разберешься. Если дальше будешь задавать тут вопросы, то ответов не дождешься т.к. ответ дан, даже с комментариями, их нужно просто прочитать понять и сделать, дальнейшее откроется само, если получится применить логику :)

Comment: если получится...

Comment: гы, скорее всего да - если получится.

Answer (score 1):

Ну любой сайт с регистрацией на нём подразумевает запись в таблице "пользователь", соответственно и все линки на профили и ссылки на страницах генерируются исходя из данной таблицы, от части. т.е. страница

***profile{id}*** (это все к примеру) сразу выдаст твой аккаунт, если ты вошел в систему.(изменив {id} на другой id можно получить страницу другого пользователя) можно поэкспериментировать на Хешкоде, правда тут tit и ник добавляется в конце :)

Советую просто почитать про разработку новостей на сайте, чтобы понять как выводятся новости, как организовывается постраничная навигация, как можно новости разбить на категории и т.д. это самые простые примеры, на которых можно понять логику и суть решения многих вопросов, т.к. многие вопросы уже решены и писать их заного нет смысла, главное разобраться как устроено построение ссылок на сайтах, и почему именно по ссылке **news/russian-best** или **news/1** выводится статья **"Россия Лучшая"**

Тут сразу браться за соц сеть задавая подобные вопросы, вообще не советую, ничего хорошего из этого вообще не получиться.

Comment: Это уже известно.
Задача - пользователь заполняет форму, данные передаются в базу и на их основе генерируется страница (не соц сеть)
Но я туплю и никак немогу понять как это страница появляется на хосте? 
Если он ввел Artem => будет www.website/Artem (почему нет расширения понятно - mod_rewrite)
и теперь если в обратиться http://www.website/Artеm - любому пользователю будет видна эта страница
то есть на хосте данная (новая) страница существует - но каким образом она там появилась? мы же на сервер ничего не загружали.

Comment: Я же специально про НОВОСТИ написал, поучись на них!

> http://www.website/Artеm  

из Таблицы будет выбран логин как в данном случае, и если он есть то выведем страницу, если такого логина нет то покажем фигу.

> http://www.website/WTF  

поищем пользователя WTF найдет хорошо не найдет плохо. А как написал @Palmervan то тут дело не в программировании.

Answer (score 0):

Страница каждый раз генерируется, используя информацию из БД.

Comment: Доперло...

Answer (score 0):

знаешь, попробуй написать чат с личной страницей, там начнешь разбераться